# Best way to find all unique combinations of elements of an array?

Tags: arrays, rust, functional-programming, iterator

I have an array of some particular ints, and I want to find all the unique combinations (by addition) of these ints. I'm sure there's a way to do this functionally; I'm trying to avoid the iterative way of shoving for loops inside of for loops. I'm using Rust in this case, but this question is more generally a, "functional programming, how do?" take.

My first thought is that I should just zip every entry in `v` with every other entry, reduce them by addition to a single element, and filter duplicates. This is O(|v|^2), which feels bad, meaning I'm probably missing something fairly obvious to the functional whiz kids. Also I'm not even sure how to do it, I'd probably use a for loop to construct my new massive array.

My first pass: note that `v` holds all the numbers I care about.

````rust
let mut massive_arr = Vec::new();
for &elem in v.iter(){
  for &elem2 in v.iter(){
  massive_arr.push((elem,elem2));
  }
}
let mut single_massive = Vec::new();
for &tuple in massive_arr.iter(){
  single_massive.push(tuple.0 + tuple.1);
}
single_massive.dedup();
let summand: usize = single_massive.iter().sum();                                                println!("The sum of all that junk is {:?}", summand);```
````

Help me baptize my depraved iterations in the pure light of functional programming.

**edited:** I threw up an example before as I was still figuring out the implementation that actually worked, and the question was more of a, how do I do this better question. The thing above now actually works (but is still ugly!).

Comment: Have you checked out `itertools::combinations` https://docs.rs/itertools/0.4.4/itertools/struct.Combinations.html?

Comment: By looking at your code, I assume that by combinations you mean two ints, and the criterion for uniqueness is that the two ints add up to the same number.

Comment: I think O(n^2) is asymptotically optimal: Consider the case where `v` contains `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...`: In this case, all pairs of numbers yield a different sum, so you have n*(n-1)/2 unique items to collect, which is quadratic.

Comment: Ah, neat, thinking about it like a graph and O(n^2) does just pop out, though since we're including a single edge from each vertex to itself, it's probably actually n^2/2. Thanks @phimuemue. `Itertools::combinations` looks like an interesting type. Thanks for pointing it out @Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving on @phimuemue's answer, you can avoid the obvious duplicates like this:

```
v.iter()
 .enumerate()
 .flat_map (|(i, a)| v[i+1..].iter().map (move |b| a+b))
 .unique()    // May not be needed or what you really want, see note below
 .sum()
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=059d0a9f4259f6f16080d53a5f7eea6a)

Note however that this may not give you the answer you really want if multiple pairs of numbers have the same sum. For example, given `vec![1, 2, 3, 4]` as input, which do you expect:

- `(1+2) + (1+3) + (1+4) + (2+3) + (2+4) + (3+4) = 30`
- or `3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 25` because `1+4 == 2+3 == 5` is only counted once?

Comment: Cool, learned a bunch here. First, there's two errors of interpretation (fault mine); you were correct to infer that I wanted only unique sums, in which case 25 would be correct. Though to be precise, I also wanted to include the diagonal, which would include (4,4) -> 8.

Comment: Second, for anyone reading this later (as I am very likely to) the really neat thing here is that you taught me to use `flat_map` (and `flatten`) as a functional method to literally "flatten" recursive iteration loops of predictable depth.

Comment: Last, I learned some mechanics of using iterators: in particular, what the `move` operator is good for which I'll explain now. Your solution gives a neat example of this: after constructing the indices we care about with `enumerate`, we need to `flatten` a pair of iterations, one from index 0 to the end, the other from index i to the end. To do so, we build a second iterator, from `v[i..].iter()`, which iterates over the tuples (of form (a,b)). We `map` those tuples to single values in the inner closure. We need the move command, because the outer closure doesn't have ownership of b, only a.

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly use itertools (I do not have a compiler at hand, but you probably get the idea):

```
use itertools::Itertools;

iproduct!(v.iter(), v.iter())     // construct all pairs
    .map(|tuple| tuple.0+tuple.1) // sum each pair
    .unique()                     // de-duplicate (uses a HashMap internally)
    .sum()                        // sum up
```

All this is still O(n^2) which is -- as far as I see -- asymptotically optimal, because all pairs of numbers might be needed.

To avoid the obvious duplicates, you can use `tuple_combinations`:

```
v.iter()
    .tuple_combinations()
    .map(|(a, b)| a+b)
    .unique()
    .sum()
```

Comment: That looks plausible! I suppose I didn't see the `iproduct!` macro until someone mentioned `itertools` above. I am still curious if we could go from v^2 cartesian products to v^2/2, but the only way that I know of is by iteratively looping.